# An error occurred. Contact a system administrator or refer to the Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK troubleshooting guide

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sdk, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

Following [this blog](http://scaleablesolutions.com/connecting-asp-net-mvc-application-to-dynamic-crm/#comment-764), we've setup the `SaveAccount` method inside `DAL_AccountEntity.cs` class for our Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK project.

Whenever we try to add a new record using [`OrganizationService.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.client.services.organizationservice.create(v=crm.7).aspx)

It throws the following error:

> ## Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> ---
>
> ***An error occurred. Contact a system administrator or refer to the Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK troubleshooting guide.***
>
> **Exception Details:** System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: An error occurred. Contact a system administrator or refer to the Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK troubleshooting guide.

**Source Error:**

```
Line 28:                 if (objAccountModel.AccountID == Guid.Empty)
Line 29:                 {
Line 30:                     objAccountModel.AccountID = service.Create(AccountEntity);
Line 31:                 }
Line 32:                 else
```

Comment: Solved the issue by following [Vijay's comments](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/120680)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an OnPremise, try adding includeExceptionDetailInFaults in the CRM's web.config so that you can get more information of the exception, or alternatively, look for errors in the Server's event viewer where CRM is installed.

Maybe the connection string is wrong, or the user account doesn't have access, it could be anything without knowing the exception details...

Comment: It's [online](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm-online) trial version - we're still evaluating the product

Answer (score 1):

This line looks fishy

```
AccountEntity["primarycontactid"] = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference { Id = objAccountModel.PrimaryContact.Id, LogicalName = "account" };
```

The Id assigned is of the object `PrimaryContact` but the LogicalName is set as `account`, try changing the LogicalName to `contact` or try assigning the correct `accountid`.